Las propiedades de mi objeto creado no son visibles dentro de img.onload que está en un método de esa misma función
Estoy empezando a practicar javascript orientado a objetos y para ello intenté repetir mi código de una página web pero en base a clases y objetos.
Cuando en un método incluyo el evento img.onload = function(){...} la propiedad del objeto me tira undefined, mientras que en el método en sí mismo sí es visible. Lo puedo comprender con let y const pues simplemente lo reemplazo con var y se acabó, pero en propiedades de un objeto no lo comprendo.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    'use strict';

    class lightBox{
        constructor(id){
            if(document.getElementById(id) !== null){
                this.lightboxDiv = document.getElementById(id);
                this.ar;
                this.al;
                this.ready = true;
                this.insertImg = function(anchorTag){
                    this.lightboxDiv.innerHTML = '<div id="image-show"><figure><img class="loading_gif" src="img/loading.gif"></figure></div>';
                    this.lightboxDiv.style.display = 'block';
                    if(this.lightboxDiv.querySelector('div#image-show')){
                        this.lightboxDiv.innerHTML = '';
                    }
                    this.lightboxDiv.appendChild(this.equis);
                    this.div.appendChild(this.div_out);
                    this.lightboxDiv.appendChild(this.div);
        
                    anchorTag.href !== null ? this.img.src = anchorTag.href.replace('thumb', 'show') : this.img.src = anchorTag;
        
                    this.img.onload = function(){
                        if(window.innerWidth >= 800){
                            this.div_out.className = 'ancho';// A PARTIR DE AQUI Y EN TODO EL METODO ONLOAD LAS PROPIEDADES DE MI OBJETO YA NO SON VISIBLES. ME SALEN UNDEFINED.
                            this.div_out.style.margin = '5% auto';
                            var encajar = (window.innerHeight/100)*80,
                            ratio = img.height/encajar;
                            this.div_out.style.height = encajar+'px';
                            this.div_out.style.width = img.width/ratio+'px';
                        }else if(window.innerWidth >= 600){
                            this.img.style.width = 100+'%';
                            this.div_out.style.width =70+'%';
                            this.div_out.style.height = 'auto';
                        }else{
                            this.img.style.width = 100+'%';
                            this.div_out.style.width = 95+'%';
                            this.div_out.style.height = 'auto';
                        }
                    };
                    this.slideshowListeners(this.img);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        generarDivSurrounded(){
            let div = document.createElement('div'),
            div_out = document.createElement('div'),
            div_cont = document.createElement('div'),
            fig = document.createElement('figure'),
            equis = document.createElement('div'),
            img = document.createElement('img'),
            ar = document.createElement('a'),
            al = document.createElement('a'),
            div_comp = document.createElement('div');
            ar.innerHTML = '<span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>';
            al.innerHTML = '<span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>';
            ar.className = 'right';
            al.className = 'left';
            div_comp.innerHTML = '<div><a><span class="fab fa-facebook"></span><p>Compartir</p></a><a><span class="fab fa-twitter"></span><p>Tweet</p></a><a><span class="fab fa-google-plus"></span><p>Google +</p></a></div>';
            equis.className = 'equis';
            equis.innerHTML = '<span class="fa fas fa-times"></span>';
            div.setAttribute('id', 'image-show');//
            div_out.setAttribute('id', 'dimensiones_box');
            div_out.appendChild(ar);
            div_out.appendChild(al);
            fig.appendChild(img);
            div_cont.appendChild(fig);
            div_out.appendChild(div_cont);
            div_out.appendChild(div_comp);
            this.div = div;
            this.equis = equis;
            this.img = img;
            this.div_out = div_out;
            this.ar = ar;
            this.al = al;
        }
        slideshowListeners = function(img){
            this.al.addEventListener('click', function(){
                img.setAttribute('class', 'loading_gif');
                img.setAttribute('src', 'img/loading.gif');
            })
        }
        
    }
    
    class ajax{
        constructor(){

        }
    }

    class ubicadorDeAncla{
        constructor(clickTag){
            if(clickTag.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'span' || clickTag.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'p'){
                clickTag = clickTag.parentNode.parentNode;
            }else if(clickTag.className.toLowerCase() === 'img-hover'){
                clickTag = clickTag.parentNode;
            }
            return clickTag;
        }
    }
    if(document.getElementById('gllr_anchors') !== null){
        var lbx = new lightBox('lightbox');
        if(lbx.ready === true){
            let callback = new gestionar(lbx);
            document.getElementById('gllr_anchors').addEventListener('click', callback.general);
        }        
    }
})

¿Por qué no son visibles las propiedades de el objeto en cuestión dentro del método img.onload?

Dándole vueltas al asunto, evalué con un console.log(this) dentro y fuera del método img.onload y descubrí que el contexto no era el mismo, y recordé de mi libro "secrets of javascript ninja" que:

La función funcion(){...} al ser llamada cambia el contexto a el objeto "img" y que...
La función "arrow" o flecha deja el contexto como esta.

Así que probé y ese era el problema; cambié:
img.onload = function(){this.div...}

por:
img.onload = ()=>{this.div...} 

y ya no me dio undefined.

Si lo leen y desean dejar algún comentario de si estoy usando mal las clases y las instancias o si me estoy expresando mal con los términos "contexto", "objetos", etc. o de las clases, siéntanse libres de escribirme por favor, ya que estoy practicando y por ende aprendiendo con las clases, instancias, sus propiedades, métodos y demás para familiarizarme más.


Comentario temporal ya que los comentarios son solo para solicitar aclaraciones: mis felicitaciones por depurar tu código tratando de buscar el origen del problema. Preguntas y respuestas como la tuya (de principiante, pero bien formuladas y completas) enriquecen el sitio :)
